# Xamarin: get if a pangesture touch is inside a certain element

Tags: xamarin.forms, touch, coordinates, uipangesturerecognizer

Is there a way to check if a touch of a pangesture is inside a certain element, like a `Frame`?

I added a `PanGestureRecognizer` to my screen. In my screen I have two `Frame` containing two `Image`. What I want is that when I move my finger on the screen I got noticed when my finger ends on one of that frames. I know how to get my finger coordinates (`e.TotalX; e.TotalY;`) and my thought was to check if they are inside the bounds of the frames, but I don't know how.

Any suggestion?

CODE

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += PanUpdated;
        mainLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);

        dog = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.Blue,
            Padding = 4,
            Content = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromResource("AccessibilityImagesSound.Immagini.dog.png"),
                Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
            },

        };
        AutomationProperties.SetIsInAccessibleTree(dog, true);
        AutomationProperties.SetName(dog, "dog");
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(dog, new Rectangle(0.2, 0.5, 0.30, 0.30));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(dog, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        mainLayout.Children.Add(dog);



        cat = new Frame
        {
            BorderColor = Color.Blue,
            Padding = 4,
            Content = new Image
            {
                Source = ImageSource.FromResource("AccessibilityImagesSound.Immagini.cat.png"),
                Aspect = Aspect.Fill,
            },

        };
        AutomationProperties.SetIsInAccessibleTree(cat, true);
        AutomationProperties.SetName(cat, "cat");
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(cat, new Rectangle(0.8, 0.5, 0.30, 0.30));
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(cat, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
        mainLayout.Children.Add(cat);

    }

    private void PanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:

                break;
            case GestureStatus.Running:

                //Here I think I have to check E.TotalX and e.TotalY

                break;
            case GestureStatus.Completed:
            case GestureStatus.Canceled: 
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to get location of Touch in xamarin is through native touch gestures.

Native gestures can be used using the `Effects` and [this MSDocs link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/effects/touch-tracking) has full implementation of it.

Using the TouchEffect the exact location of the touch can be fetched easily. A sample to change color of the touched frame is given below.

XAML:

```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.Effects>
            <touch:TouchEffect TouchAction="Grid_TouchAction"/>
        </Grid.Effects>
        <Frame
            Grid.Row="1"
            BackgroundColor="Green"
            x:Name="leftFrame"/>
        <Frame
            Grid.Row="1"
            Grid.Column="1"
            BackgroundColor="Blue"
            x:Name="rightFrame"/>
    </Grid>
```

CS :

```
    private void Grid_TouchAction(object sender, TouchTracking.TouchActionEventArgs args)
    {
        switch (args.Type)
        {
            case TouchActionType.Moved:
                if (leftFrame.Bounds.Contains(args.Location))
                {
                    leftFrame.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    leftFrame.BackgroundColor = Color.Green;
                }

                if (rightFrame.Bounds.Contains(args.Location))
                {
                    rightFrame.BackgroundColor = Color.Red;
                }
                else
                {
                    rightFrame.BackgroundColor = Color.Blue;
                }
                break;
        }
    }
```

UI working:

[image]

Change the TouchAction event handler as per your requirement.

Comment: @Poli97, I think you can not get mouse x/y coordinates from TapGestureRecognizer, PinchGestureRecognizer or PanGestureRecognizer class, as Nikhileshwar's code, you need implement custom renderers TouchEffect  for each platform to get location.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT ok got it thanks, and do you know a simple way to apply that TouchEffect to implement drag and drop for `Label` or some other elements?